# How to use concatenated strings as a name in c() function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to use concatenated strings as element names in a vector? I've got a `text1` variable which contains a column name, but at the later stage I create another columns with some suffices added to `name`. After gathering the data those newly created name become a factor variable `key` which I would like to use in `scale_fill_manual` and assign colors to factor levels. But I can't figure out how this can be passed as a vector names. A code is shown below:

```
text1 <- 'name'
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_area(aes(x,y, fill = key)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(paste0(text1, '_suffix') = 'blue', 
                               paste0(text1, '_suffix2') = 'red)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you define the fill values vector outside `ggplot()` first? e.g. `fill.values = c('blue', 'red'); names(fill.values) = paste0(text1, c('_suffix', '_suffix2'))`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for `setNames`

```
text1 <- "what"
setNames(c("blue", "red"), paste0(text1, c('_suffix', '_suffix2')))

 what_suffix what_suffix2
      "blue"        "red"
```